# Deploying Sharepoint Sites to User OneDrive using InTune

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive, intune

We are replicating our on-premise mapped drives to Sharepoint Team Sites, then deploying them to users via OneDrive Team Automount using Intune. Some 'sites' will be available to all users, whereas others will be on a per user/per department basis.

Is there a way to configure multiple instances of the same policy (in this case `Configure team site libraries to sync automatically (User)`) so that the values from multiple policies all get applied?